# how to set custom background using CSS / HTML5 JqueryMobile

Tags: android, css, html, jquery-mobile

i got a problem to set custom background into my jquerymobile android apps. The problem is after i add the panel into the page. basically i just using this css code below.

```
.ui-page { background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

to set my backround, but after i put the code below

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
<!-- panel content goes here -->
</div><!-- /panel -->

<!-- header -->
<!-- content -->
<!-- footer -->
```

The background is blank, can someone please help me.

Comment: Is this patch correct : url(images/bg.jpg);

Comment: yes the path is correct @tgrll

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
.ui-page, .ui-content { 
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg) !important; 
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important; 
}
```

When overriding default jquery mobile classes you must override it with !important. Without it jQuery Mobile will just use default values.

Comment: I already override it but still the background image is blank. @gajotres

Comment: Then override .ui-content, it covers .ui-page